Singular values on streching the vectors
For the following statement: for a vector $x$ and a matrix $A$, if the vector $x$ is not in the null space of $A$, the vector $x$ will at least be stretched by the smallest non-zero singular value, i.e. the output vector's norm will be at least the input's norm times the smallest non-zero singular value. Is this statement true?
For example, for a 3-by-3, rank 2 matrix $A$, it admits a SVD:
$$A = USV^T, S = \begin{matrix}
\sigma_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sigma_2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}$$
apply $A$ to a vector $x$, which is not in the null space of $A$, the norm of the output $||y||=||Ax||$ will be at least $\sigma_2 ||x||$. Is this statement true?
I discover this pattern when trying out multiple examples but don't know if it is true generally and if so, how to prove it.
Thank you!

The vector has to be in the orthogonal complement of the null space, for the diagonal matrix $S$ take $x=(\epsilon,0,1)$, then $Sx \ne 0$ but $|Sx|$ is very small compared to $|x|$.

Thank you for your response! Do you mean the vector has to be in the orthogonal complement of the null space for this statement to be true?
